# (Ionic/React) Tab not displaying content properly

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

Im having some problems on rendering some pages on tabs. It works sometimes, but most of the time it shows a blank page, the thing is at the console, it doesn’t show any error and even it shows my console.log from the right page.

Here is my code on every page:

```
*app.tsx*
```

```
setupIonicReact();

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonRouterOutlet>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Login />
        </Route>
        <Route component={Register} path="/register" exact/>
        <Route component={Menu} path="/app"/>
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
);
```

```
*menu.tsx*
```

```
const Menu: React.FC = () => {
    const paths = [
        {name: 'Dados Gerais', url: '/app/data', icon: analyticsOutline },
        {name: 'Arrecadação', url: '/app/dataArrecadacao', icon: cashOutline},
        {name: 'Contábil', url: '/app/dataContabil', icon: calculatorOutline},
        {name: 'Educação', url: '/app/dataFundeb', icon: bookOutline},
        {name: 'Pessoal', url: '/app/dataFolha', icon: personCircleOutline},
        {name: 'Saúde', url: '/app/dataSaude', icon: fitnessOutline},
        {name: 'Diária', url: '/app/dataDiarias', icon: clipboardOutline},
        {name: 'Configuração', url:'/app/settings', icon: settingsOutline },
    ];
    return (
        <IonPage>
            <IonMenu contentId="main">
                <IonHeader>
                    <IonToolbar color={'secondary'}>
                        <IonTitle>Menu</IonTitle>
                    </IonToolbar>
                </IonHeader>
                <IonContent>
                    {paths.map((item, index) => (
                        <IonMenuToggle key = {index} autoHide={false}>
                            <IonItem detail={false} routerLink={item.url} routerDirection="none">
                                <IonIcon slot='start' icon={item.icon}/>
                            {item.name}
                            </IonItem>
                        </IonMenuToggle>
                        ))}
                        <IonMenuToggle autoHide={false}>
                            <IonButton color='secondary' expand='full' routerLink='/' routerDirection="none">
                                <IonIcon slot='start' icon={logOutOutline}/>
                                    Logout
                                </IonButton> 
                        </IonMenuToggle>
                    </IonContent>
            </IonMenu>
            <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
                <Route exact={true} path="/app/data" component={Data}/>
                <Route exact={true} path="/app/dataArrecadacao" component={DadosArrecadacao}/>
                <Route exact={true} path="/app/dataFolha" component={DadosFolha}/>
                <Route exact={true} path="/app/dataFundeb" component={dadosFundeb}/>
                <Route exact={true} path="/app/dataContabil" component={dadosContabil}/>
                <Route exact={true} path="/app/dataSaude" component={DadosSaude}/>
                <Route exact={true} path="/app/dataDiarias" component={DadosDiarias}/>
                <Route exact={true} path="/app/settings" component={Settings}/>
                <Route exact={true} path="/app">
                    <Redirect to="/app/data"/>
                </Route>
            </IonRouterOutlet>
        </IonPage>
    );
};
```

And each of those pages (data...) have this code rendering the right tabs

```
*data.tsx*
```

```
return (
        <IonTabs>
            <IonTabBar slot='bottom'>
                <IonTabButton tab="Dados" href="/app/data/dataGeral">
                    <IonIcon onClick={DadosGerais} icon={pieChart}/>
                    <IonLabel>Dados</IonLabel>
                </IonTabButton>
                <IonTabButton tab="Graficos" href="/app/data/graficos">
                    <IonIcon onClick={GraficosGeral} icon={statsChart}/>
                    <IonLabel>Gráficos</IonLabel>
                </IonTabButton>
            </IonTabBar>

            <IonRouterOutlet>
                <Route exact={true} path="/app/data/dataGeral" component={DadosGerais}/>
                <Route exact={true} path="/app/data/graficos" component={GraficosGeral}/>
                <Route exact path="/app/data">
                    <Redirect to="/app/data/dataGeral"/>
                </Route>
            </IonRouterOutlet>
        </IonTabs>
    );
```

also a video to visualize what is happening (ignore the data not showing up, the api was out when I recorded this videos)

https://clipchamp.com/watch/UKjn03MiFBf

Can someone help me with that please?

I have tried to add 'onClick' on eache icon, and did not work